# Best way for sending automatic email periodically in Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi I need help regarding sending email periodically in Spring mvc,can anyone suggest which is the best way and how i can achieve this,

Comment: schedule the period using spring timertask. Here you get some example - [1](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/21/2-ways-to-execute-timer-tasks-in-spring-3/), [2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/scheduling.html)

Comment: Use quartz, schedule cron job which runs periodically. Very easy to configure, you can read this: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/

Answer (score 3):

If it has to be from inside the application, you could add a Spring `@Scheduled` Service within it, and let this one send out your emails.

Akin to

```
// once every hour, on top of the hour, Mondays to Fridays
@Scheduled(cron = * 0 * * * MON-FRI)
public void sendMail() {
   //mail stuff here
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, great and elegant!

Comment: Great answer, but i need it inside my application and with able  to  start and stop this service from jsp, how can i achive this.

Comment: You could use a global flag, some boolean field called shouldExecute or something, and only send mails if true. If false, the method would trigger and just do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Run scheduled tasks outside of your application. Use [crontab](http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) or the like.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you would use a Quartz schedule to handle this.  There is some documentation about scheduling tasks here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good compatibility with Spring 3 + QuartZ Job Scheduler. Using QuartZ you can schedule a cron trigger which can easily send emails periodically and the best thing in this approach is, everything is very easy to implement and configurable. I would suggest you to please go through the below links:

- http://quartz-scheduler.org/
- http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/