# How to send email from spring boot application automatically each end of day?

Tags: spring-boot, email, jakarta-mail, jobs

I want to start a new project where the application send me an email each end of the day but i don't know how to start.
if any one can tell me what to use and how to configure the application to send emails automatically each day in order to begin my app and i will ask technical questions once i will get errors :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051958/best-way-for-sending-automatic-email-periodically-in-spring-mvc . This holds true for Spring boot as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Scheduler in your spring boot application to schedule your email task.
The Spring Framework provides abstractions for asynchronous execution and scheduling of tasks with the TaskExecutor and TaskScheduler interfaces, respectively. [more details](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/).

Example"

```
@Component
    public class MailScheduler {    

        @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 * * ?")
        public void sendMail() {
               // Your mail logic will go here
              System.out.println("Scheduled task running");

        }
    }
```

Here cron = "0 0 12 * * ?" , means this task will execute every night 12 PM

You can customize it based on your requirement,Below is a breakdown of the components that build a cron expression.

- Seconds can have values 0-59 or the special characters , - * / .
- Minutes can have values 0-59 or the special characters , - * / .
- Hours can have values 0-59 or the special characters , - * / .
- Day of month can have values 1-31 or the special characters , - * ? / L W C .
- Month can have values 1-12, JAN-DEC or the special characters , - * / .
- Day of week can have values 1-7, SUN-SAT or the special characters , - * ? / L C # .
- Year can be empty, have values 1970-2099 or the special characters , - * / .

You can also generate cron based on the below online ui tools :

- https://crontab.guru/
- http://www.cronmaker.com/?1